# How to add a bounce effect to a JS function

Tags: javascript

How would I add a "bounce" effect to this slide-in function;

```
$(window).load(function(){

$('.show').hover(function() {
$('.tool_hover').animate({
    'left':'190px'},
                        'slow');
},function() {
$('.tool_hover').animate({
    'left':'3000px'},
                        'slow');
});

});
```

so that when the "tool_hover" completes its slide in to 190px it bounces left to right before coming to a complete stop.

Answer (score 0):

Add the jQuery easing plugin:

http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/

Then add 'easeInOutBack' to your animation syntax. It looks like this:

```
$('.show').hover(function() {
    $('.tool_hover').animate({'left':'190px'}, {left:'easeOutBack'}, 'slow');
},function() {
    $('.tool_hover')$('.tool_hover').animate({'left':'3000px'}, {left:'easeOutBack'}, 'slow');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery UI has bounce effect.

[UI/Effects/Bounce](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Bounce)

Comment: how would I implement this into the current function?

Comment: Using jQuery UI solely for this purpose would be a huge overkill.